# combining these two lua formatting lines into one

Tags: lua, formatting, gsub

is there any way to combine these last two formatting lines of code into one?

```
str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "

str = str:gsub("%p", {[","] = " >" }) -- replaces ',' with '>'
str = string.sub(str, 1, #str - 2) --removes last whitespace + comma
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `str = str:gsub(',','>'):sub(1,-3)`

Comment: hzm weird i tried the same before making the post and it didnt work for me. I guess that same line of code needed to be touched by your magic fingers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "
str = str:sub(1, #str-2):gsub("%p", {[","] = " >" })
```

This will do what you want it to do.

Egor's is a bit more elegant, though:

```
str = str:gsub(',',' > '):sub(1,-3)
```

Comment: According to his last comment: `:gsub("[> ]*$", "")`